# is a function meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$ except for isolated singularities and assume that there exists an $R>0$ and $M>0$ such that for $|z|>R  \,\,\,|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^{\alpha}}$ where $\alpha >1$. I want to show that f has finitely many singularities and all of them inside $|z|\leq R$ so f is meromorphic. Any help would be great.

Comment: The only other possibility is an essential singularity, for which points near the singularity can have any complex value except for one number $w$, and you cannot write the bound on $|f(z)|$ as you have above.

Comment: I know the properties about essential singularities you wrote but how that means f has only finitely many singularities, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is bounded on $|z|> R$, any singularity in $\{|z|> R\}$ is removable. All other singularities are in $\{|z|\le R\}$. Since the singularities are isolated and $\{|z|\le R\}$ is compact, there are only a finite number of them. This does not imply that $f$ is meromorphic, since some of the singularities could be essential. Consider for example $f(z)=e^{1/z^2}-1$. If $|z|>1$ then $|f(z)|\le M/|z|^2$, and $z=0$ is an essential singularity.